# Sql2o with postgres, No results were returned by the query

Tags: java, postgresql, sql2o

The other questions I've found with this title all deal with non-SELECT queries.  I'm using Java 8, Sql2o 1.5.4, and postgresql 9.5.3.

My UserService looks like:

```
public class UserService {
    private final PGService pgService;

    public UserService(PGService _pgs) {
        this.pgService = _pgs;
    }

    public User getUserById(int id) {
        String sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, team_id teamId FROM users WHERE id = :id;--";
        User user;
        try (Connection c = pgService.getConnection()) {
            user = c.createQuery(sql)
                    .addParameter("id", id)
                    .executeAndFetchFirst(User.class);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

My user looks like:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String passhash;
    private int teamId;
    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

My test looks like:

```
public class UserServiceTest {
    private static UserService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws ConfigurationException, IOException {
        this.service = new UserService(new PGService());
    }

    @Test
    public void returnsBiffUser() {
        User biff = service.getUserById(3);
        assertTrue(biff != null && biff.getLastname() == "Biff");
    }
}
```

When I execute the SQL directly against the database I get the expected record, and team_id is NULL in this case.

When I run the test, I get the following exception:

```
org.sql2o.Sql2oException: Database error: No results were returned by the query.

    at org.sql2o.Query$ResultSetIterableBase.<init>(Query.java:332)
    at org.sql2o.Query$10.<init>(Query.java:412)
    at org.sql2o.Query.executeAndFetchLazy(Query.java:412)
    at org.sql2o.Query.executeAndFetchFirst(Query.java:480)
    at org.sql2o.Query.executeAndFetchFirst(Query.java:469)
    at services.UserService.getUserById(UserService.java:24)
    at services.UserServiceTest.returnsBiffUser(UserServiceTest.java:25)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:115)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
    at org.sql2o.Query$ResultSetIterableBase.<init>(Query.java:328)
```

Why is this happening?  How can I fix it?  My PGService tests are passing and it is created from a DBCP2 BasicDataSource.  Please let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: I would say there is no user with id = 3 in your table your test connects to. You are probably connecting to a different database then with your SQL client. Or your tests don't setup the test data correctly.  Additionally: `biff.getLastname() == "Biff"` is **wrong**. Do ***not*** compare Strings using `==`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks man, it was actually my PGService that was causing the problem.  Once I fixed that my test indeed failed for the reason you pointed out regarding == vs .equal().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was not in the UserService, it was in my PGService class.  Which was:

```
public class PGService {
    private final Sql2o connectionPool;

    public PGService() throws ConfigurationException, IOException {
        Config cfg = loadConfig("dbconfig.json");
        if (cfg == null) {
            throw new ConfigurationException("Could not load dbconfig.");
        }
        BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
        bds.setUsername(cfg.getUsername());
        bds.setPassword(cfg.getPassword());
        bds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        bds.setUrl(cfg.getUrl());
        bds.setInitialSize(1);
        connectionPool = new Sql2o(bds);
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return this.connectionPool.open();
    }
}
```

The fix and explanation below, from the Sql2o Google group fixed my problem and is tightly related to the error surrounding RETURNING syntax when using postgres.

> The "syntax error at or near RETURNING" is caused by an
>   incompatibility between the way sql2o is handling automatically
>   generated keys in the database and the postgres jdbc driver. When
>   using postgres, that exception is thrown when sql2o checks if there
>   was generated any keys in the db. The solution is to never check for
>   keys, except when you explicitly expect there to be generated a key.
>
> This is handled in sql2o by the PostgresQuirks class. So, when
>   creating you Sql2o instance, use one of the constructor overloads that
>   takes a Quriks instance as parameter:
>
> Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o(bds, new PostgresQuirks());
>
> That should fix it!  And make sure to remove the '--' after your
>   query.

Anyways, I hope this helps anyone who encounters this issue in the future.

Cheers.